# Pull ANY Arduino pin using C# serial.write

Tags: c#, arduino, serial-port

I am writing an application in C# that will send a serial.write to my COM port. All the examples I've seen of C# controlling the Arduino's pins focus on pulling only one pin. Below is my code. I can only pull pin 9 to HIGH right now, none of the other read commands work. Where's the schoolboy error? :)

Arduino code:

```
void setup() {
  // Define inputs and outputs
  pinMode(0, INPUT);
  pinMode(1, INPUT);
  pinMode(2, INPUT);
  pinMode(3, INPUT);
  pinMode(4, INPUT);
  pinMode(5, INPUT);
  pinMode(6, INPUT);
  pinMode(7, INPUT);
  pinMode(8, INPUT);
  pinMode(9, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(10, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(11, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(12, OUTPUT);
  // Begin Serial communication at a baudrate of 9600:
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {

   if (Serial.read() == 'a')
   {
      digitalWrite(9, HIGH);
   }
   else if (Serial.read() == 'b')
   {
      digitalWrite(9, LOW);
   }
   
   else if (Serial.read() == 'c')
   {
      digitalWrite(10, HIGH);
   }
   else if (Serial.read() == 'd')
   {
      digitalWrite(10, LOW);
   }

   else if (Serial.read() == 'e')
   {
      digitalWrite(11, HIGH);
   }
   else if (Serial.read() == 'f')
   {
      digitalWrite(11, LOW);
   }

   else if (Serial.read() == 'g')
   {
      digitalWrite(12, HIGH);
   }
   else if (Serial.read() == 'h')
   {
      digitalWrite(12, LOW);
   }
   delay(100);
   
}
```

C# code

```
private void btnOP9on_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            serialPort1.Write("a");
        }

        private void btnOP9off_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            serialPort1.Write("b");
        }
```

Comment: Serial.read() consumes the character out of serial.  SO the first if calls read() and gets an 'a' it works.  But if you send a 'e' then the first if reads it and compares it to 'a' which it is not, then the second if statement reads another character and if there's not one there then it gets a -1 and compares that to 'b' which it is not.  Read from serial once at the top of all that and compare the same thing all the way down.  Don't forget available() to see if there's anything to read.  This is ALL covered in any number of basic tutorials on reading from serial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading a character from serial consumes it.  You can't read the same character again.  You need to read from serial ONCE and then compare that to all the different things.

```
void loop() {
   char c = 0;
   if(Serial.available()){
     c = Serial.read();
   }

   if (c == 'a')
   {
      digitalWrite(9, HIGH);
   }
   else if (c == 'b')
   {
      digitalWrite(9, LOW);
   }
   
   else if (c == 'c')
   {
      digitalWrite(10, HIGH);
   }
   else if (c == 'd')
   {
      digitalWrite(10, LOW);
   }

   else if (c == 'e')
   {
      digitalWrite(11, HIGH);
   }
   else if (c == 'f')
   {
      digitalWrite(11, LOW);
   }

   else if (c == 'g')
   {
      digitalWrite(12, HIGH);
   }
   else if (c == 'h')
   {
      digitalWrite(12, LOW);
   }
   delay(100);
   
}
```

Comment: Marvelous, your earlier comment got me on the right path. I refreshed this page and our code is near identical now. Thanks!